# Call a procedure till children exists plsql

Tags: plsql

I have one table in plsql like this

```
PK_ID    DEPT_ID   SUB_DEPT_ID
   1           1          3
   2           1          4
   3           1          5
   4           3          6
   5           3          7
   6           6          9
..............
```

I have to execute a certain procedure till the children of some DEPT_ID found, suppose I take 1 DEPT_ID then procedure should execute for 3,4,5, then first it should execute for 3 if children of 3 exists(here they are 6,7, again it will execute for children of 6 that is 9 and so on), then for 4 if children for 4 exists (here it does not exists), then for children of 5(here it does not exists) and so on, maybe i need to prepare some kind of recursive function for this but don't know much about how to achieve this, any help please?

Comment: So you want to execute the process for all dept_id's except those that don't have any children? (e.g. dept_id = 4 wouldn't be processed?)

Comment: Also, does every sub_dept_id appear in the dept_id column?

Comment: No not necessary, as you can see sub_dept_id 4 does not appear in det_id, moreover I will have one main DeptId at beginning, and I want to execute process until the child of that deptId (and child of child of that DeptId and so on...) exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hierarchical query might work well here.

Try using a query like the one shown below in a "for..loop":

```
 select dept_id, sub_dept_id, level 
   from dept_subdept 
  START WITH dept_id = 1 
connect by prior sub_dept_id=dept_id 
  order by level,sub_dept_id;
```

For example...

GIVEN: a table DEPT_SUBDEPT containing the following data:

```
   PK_ID DEPT_ID SUB_DEPT_ID
   ----- ------- -----------
     1      1       3
     2      1       4
     3      1       5
     4      3       6
     5      3       7
     6      6       9
     7      2       8
     8      2      10
     9      2       1

9 rows selected.
```

The PLSQL shown below works through the departments (identified by DEPT_ID) and children or sub-departments (identified by SUB_DEPT_ID) as described in the original problem statement:

"...take 1 DEPT_ID then procedure should execute for 3,4,5, then first it should execute for 3 if children of 3 exists(here they are 6,7, again it will execute for children of 6 that is 9 and so on), then for 4 if children for 4 exists (here it does not exists), then for children of 5(here it does not exists) and so on..."

```
set serveroutput on;

begin
for i in (
   select dept_id, sub_dept_id,level from dept_subdept
    START WITH dept_id = &START_WITH_DEPT_ID
  connect by prior sub_dept_id=dept_id
    order by level, sub_dept_id
) loop
   dbms_output.put_line('exec someProcedure('||i.dept_id||','||i.sub_dept_id||');');
end loop;
end;
/
```

```
Enter value for start_with_dept_id: 1
```

```
exec someProcedure(1,3);
exec someProcedure(1,4);
exec someProcedure(1,5);
exec someProcedure(3,6);
exec someProcedure(3,7);
exec someProcedure(6,9);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here the PLSQL is run again using START_WITH_DEPT_ID = 3:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for start_with_dept_id: 3

exec someProcedure(3,6);
exec someProcedure(3,7);
exec someProcedure(6,9);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

... and once more using START_WITH_DEPT_ID = 4
(where there are no children and nothing to do):

```
SQL> /
Enter value for start_with_dept_id: 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: this gives "Connect by loop in user data for Combination of (Dept_id,Sub_dept_id) are "(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)" then it will not work